# If request query having large result set in AWS Athena, cannot respose to result

Tags: amazon-athena

I have analyzed logdata using AWS Athena.

My analyzed table has 941009672 rows.

Athena is so fast. like this query, runtime of query is just 3 seconds.

```
select count(*) from table
```

But, If request query having large result set, athena can not response.

```
select * from table //can not response
```

In Hadoop, the above query took 4 minutes.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How did you run the query, through the Athena console or the JDBC driver?  Did you see an error, or just no response?

Comment: @James Comment is too late sorry. I tried that through Athena web console. just no response. but In hadoop(hue), I can see a response.

Comment: Does a select with a LIMIT 100 work?  I'm curious if it works at all, or if it is the volume of data.  How many data files are there?  How many bytes?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative. You can pass the path of S3 along with the query. Then, you can see the result in S3 after that, you don't need to wait for a response. You should find the file in S3 after running the query.